# How to update and delete a Pending Intent and a Notification in android

Tags: java, android

whenever i attempt to update the notification or Intent a new one is created instead which i don't want. I think the problem is that the Intents are not being identified whenever i'm trying to update it. The link to the code is below:

https://gist.github.com/Kerron-Hutton/03799ac497128919225bbbd4efaffa25

Comment: where exactly is your update taking place in the code? or rather your intended place of update in the code?

Comment: also this line data.getID(), try debug and see if the id is the one you want, i mean this id is the key to update

Comment: also the way you are passing the id, is not really reccomended, create a constants standalone class with all notification id, then base on the intent just call it. These constants are publics static final

Answer (score 4):

1. To update a `PendingIntent`, you should use the same `REQUEST_CODE` that you used before to create it.

   ```
   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   ```
2. To cancel/delete an existing `PendingIntent`, you can use `PendingIntent.cancel()` method.

   ```
   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 
                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
   ```
3. To update a `Notification`, you can use `NotificationManager.notify()` method with the `NOTIFICATION_ID` that you want to update.

   ```
   NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
   notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
   ```

   > Notification `id` should be unique within your application. If a
   >   notification with the same `id` has already been posted by your
   >   application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the
   >   updated information.
4. To cancel/remove an existing `Notification`, use NotificationManager.Cancel() method with the `NOTIFICATION_ID` that you want to cancel.

   ```
   notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
   ```

Hope this will help~